# Check Combo Box in DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: winforms, combobox

I'm searching awhile for CheckComboBox column for DataGridView in winforms, without any result. Is there written classes that implement such things (freely) in the web? I've found some other custom columns and I've found CheckComboBox implementation, but I failed to connect them together and to make them work properly... :( Thanks.

Comment: Could you post an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you'll be able to find one because a CheckBoxComboBox isn't very common, but you can write one yourself. Here is an example of a [Custom CheckedListBoxColumn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/6c68a44c-c4ab-4caf-94e9-249ec63a90d0) to get you started.

If you get stuck follow this article that takes you through the process [Create a Custom DataGridView Column](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707061).